# Font not scaling or working for iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7, ios8

I am using OpenSans font (Regular bold and semibold) it works great in iOS 7.1 on iPhone 5 and great in simulator on iPhone 5 iOS 8.3 but in iPhone 6 and 6+ iOS 8.3 it reverts to using the system font. I want this work work in interface builder but I've also tried setting it through code as well.

I've printed out the font list and got that its definitely included

```
Font Family Name = [Open Sans]
Font Names = [[OpenSans-Semibold, OpenSans, OpenSans-Bold]]
```

I've set it manually like so:

```
var font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 5)
println("font \(font)")
descLabel.font = font
```

I've run out of things to try I have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Fonts are only scaled if the entire app is scaled. If you don't provide native support for the iPhone 6 and 6+ screen sizes, nothing is scaled.

Comment: I'm using a xib for the launch screen... Is there anyway to check if it is scaling or not?

Comment: not sure if this will help but take a look at this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/89816/porting-app-iphone-6-iphone-6-plus-ios-8-top-10-tips

Comment: yeh i've already gone through that unfortunately it didn't help thanks though!

Comment: prefer `let` to `var` in these situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size 5 is insanely small. A label will refuse to permit its font to be set to a size so small that it would not be legible under any circumstances. Set the label's font to a reasonable size, like 12 or 18.

Comment: yeh should have changed that back but at any font size it doesn't use the correct font

Comment: Well it was just a guess. :) Is it logging the font correctly in your `println`?

Comment: Also what happens if you try a font that is not a custom font? Try "GillSans" for example.

Comment: I am tempted to suggest that `descLabel` is not visible in the interface. So you are changing the font of _some_ label, but it is not the one you are looking at. Try logging `descLabel` so you can learn if its frame is even on the screen.

Comment: yeh i can see descLabel it is 100% on screen

Comment: And other fonts work but your custom font doesn't? Because in that case we've shown it's a problem with custom fonts.

Comment: it started working! thanks for helping troubleshoot!

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark but I have no idea what I did!

Comment: haha well you were the only answer and spent time helping me so thank you!